# How can I pick a contact from call log?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts, phone-call, calllog

How can I pick a contact from call logs?

This is my code, but when i try `Intent.ACTION_PICK` , it doesn't work

```
Intent showCallLog = new Intent();
showCallLog.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
showCallLog.setType(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_TYPE);
context.startActivity(showCallLog);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446580/android-get-call-history-of-contact?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure whether it can be done with ACTION_PICK, if it is feasible, you can create simply a pick dialog for this, e.g.:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button btnPick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPick);
        btnPick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String[] strFields = { android.provider.CallLog.Calls._ID,
                        android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER,
                        android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME, };
                String strOrder = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC";
                final Cursor cursorCall = getContentResolver().query(
                        android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, strFields,
                        null, null, strOrder);

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        MainActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Select recent contact");
                android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface,
                            int item) {
                        cursorCall.moveToPosition(item);
                        Toast.makeText(
                                MainActivity.this,
                                cursorCall.getString(cursorCall
                                        .getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER)),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        cursorCall.close();
                        return;
                    }
                };
                builder.setCursor(cursorCall, listener,
                        android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME);
                builder.create().show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

builder.setCursor(cursorCall, listener,
                        android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME);

Changed to

```
 builder.setCursor(cursorCall, listener,
                    android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
```

as unknown numbers were not showing..the code is Working 100% , Thanks