# Where is data is stored in android Database and how to see all?

Tags: android

I want to know where is all the stored in android. Like inbox messages are stored in

```
content://sms/inbox
```

and outbox msgs in

```
content://sms/outbox
```

or may b they are not stored , but they are parsed form these areas like in this statement

```
contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"),null, null, null, null);
```

So I want to know that how to get all **"folders"** in **"content://"** or in **"content://sms/"** .
  Also I want to know where the **call logs** are stored in or from where to fetch them. Is there any way to get all these areas where these type of things are stored??

**The thing I wanna Know is How some one knows that there are inbox sms at "content://sms/inbox" and out box at "content://sms/outbox" ?? I just want to explore the whole directory, wheather Inbuilt or of App's. Please Explain the Answers**

Comment: These kinds of URLs are abstract for a reason. If they would trivially map to a "directory" on a file system they could have just used the respective `file:///` URLs. Where exactly they are stored is intentionally abstracted away. Similarly any number of handlers could be implemented to respond to various to arbitrary URLs, so there can't be a complete list of all possible URIs.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6447182/824345) post if you are interested only in Call Logs.

Data is stored in sqLite in android [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510840/where-does-android-emulator-store-sqlite-database) are few helpful answers to your query.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to view from Eclipse how or where your database is stored go to Window>Open Perspective>Other>DDMS.

Call logs check Sayyam's answer

Comment: How to check where sms are stored from ddms? I am not good at that

Comment: You can browse the directory of the emulator. For example for Nexus S you can find the messages at ./dbdata/databases/com.android.providers.telephony/mmssms.db
./data/data/com.jb.gosms/databases/gommssms.db   

The second is the gosms application.

Answer (score 0):

From the DDMS Perspective in Eclipse, use the file explorer to find your app's database from the following path.

```
data/data/your.package.name/databases
```

You can install [Questoid SQLite and XML Browser Plugin](http://www.questoid.com/Tools/CellObjectSQLiteXMLBrowser.aspx) to your Eclipse installation and will be able to browse the data from Eclipse itself.

Here is Questoid in action.
[image]